# SIPS command (image processing) is very verbose

Tags: macos, image-processing, command-line

Is there a way to use the SIPS command in the macOS terminal without it being tremendously verbose? It is verbose by default and running `> /dev/null/` still outputs to the command line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that redirection to `/dev/null` is sufficient to shut up `sips` on my iMac. For example, the following emits nothing:

```
sips -Z 1024 z.png > /dev/null
```

If you are still struggling, try redirecting `stderr` as well as `stdout`:

```
sips -Z 1024 z.png > /dev/null 2>&1
```